# How to match array inside array in karate when data inside array is dynamically changes

Tags: karate

This is the code line I am using to validate this:

```
And match response.modelGroups contains only ExpectedResonse.modelGroups
```

Actual response.modelGroups:

```
[
    {
        "defaultEscalationRate": 5,
        "description": "sample description",
        "displayOrder": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Revenue",
        "templateModels": [
            {
                "description": "TBA",
                "displayOrder": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Residential Revenue",
                "useTenureType": "TBA"
            },
            {
                "description": "TBA",
                "displayOrder": 2,
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Other Revenue",
                "useTenureType": "TBA"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "defaultEscalationRate": 5,
        "description": "sample description",
        "displayOrder": 2,
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Cost",
        "templateModels": [
            {
                "description": "TBA",
                "displayOrder": 3,
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Operating Cost",
                "useTenureType": "TBA"
            },
            {
                "description": "TBA",
                "displayOrder": 4,
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Development Cost",
                "useTenureType": "TBA"
            },
            {
                "description": "TBA",
                "displayOrder": 5,
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Land & Infrastructure Cost",
                "useTenureType": "TBA"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected response.modelGroups :

```
[
    {
        "defaultEscalationRate": 5,
        "description": "sample description",
        "displayOrder": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Revenue",
        "templateModels": [
            {
                "description": "TBA",
                "displayOrder": 2,
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Other Revenue",
                "useTenureType": "TBA"
            },
            {
                "description": "TBA",
                "displayOrder": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Residential Revenue",
                "useTenureType": "TBA"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "defaultEscalationRate": 5,
        "description": "sample description",
        "displayOrder": 2,
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Cost",
        "templateModels": [
            {
                "description": "TBA",
                "displayOrder": 3,
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Operating Cost",
                "useTenureType": "TBA"
            },
            {
                "description": "TBA",
                "displayOrder": 4,
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Development Cost",
                "useTenureType": "TBA"
            },
            {
                "description": "TBA",
                "displayOrder": 5,
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Land & Infrastructure Cost",
                "useTenureType": "TBA"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Exception after validation:
match failed: CONTAINS_ONLY

```
$[0].templateModels[0].name | not equal (STRING:STRING)
              'Residential Revenue'
              'Other Revenue'
```

I don't understand how to validate the json when it contains arrays of arrays and the data and size of these arrays are getting changed dynamically.

Comment: please PLEASE next time you ask a question, simplify it to show the concept like my answer and don't dump everything in your use-case here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `contains deep`:

```
* def expected =
"""
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "a"
      },
      {
        "name": "b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "c"
      },
      {
        "name": "d"
      },
      {
        "name": "e"
      }
    ]
  }
]
"""
* def response =
"""
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "e"
      },
      {
        "name": "d"
      },
      {
        "name": "c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "b"
      },
      {
        "name": "a"
      }
    ]
  }
]
"""
* match response contains deep expected
```

Yes there is no `contains only deep`, but you are welcome to contribute that code to Karate :)

But seriously, that kind of extreme check is not needed. If you really need to validate `contains only`, do it partially:

```
* def ids = $expected[*].id
* match response[*].id contains only ids
```

EDIT: note that newer versions of Karate support a `match contains only deep`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#match-contains-only-deep